# How to separate binary data in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oracle11g, amazon-rds

Our Oracle DB size is around 220GB and there are two tables which stores the binary data as blob columns. One of the binary table size is around 150GB and other table is 30GB. It has made it very difficult for us to take daily backups and plan for disaster recovery in another location since the database size is very huge. Want to understand how to separate out binary data from the tables and move those table data to some some centralized storage.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create a second RDS instance and move the 2 blob tables in this new instance so you will be with 2 servers:
- *Main* server : 30 GB 
- *Document* server with blob tables

You will leave multi-AZ and daily snapshots on the *Main*  server and plan snapshot on weekly maybe for the document.

**First**: backup all tables except blob tables

you can use `expdp` to export certain tables only like

```
expdp <master user>/<master pass>@source.cnrsdab7emat.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/DB schemas=SCOTT exclude=TABLE:"IN ('BLOB1', 'BLOB2')" directory= data_pump_dir dumpfile=dump.dmp
```

**Second**: create new instance and import dump

create a new db instance, make sure to provision enough space. You do not necessarily need to transfer the dmp files and you can import the DB over network link

```
create database link to_rds connect to USERX identified by PASSX using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=source.cnrsdab7emat.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<ORCL_SID>)))';
```

run impdp from the new instance

```
impdp <master user>/<master pass>@target.cnrsdab7emat.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/NEWDB network_link=to_rds directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=dump.dmp
```

**THIRD**: clean your old db

`ALTER` the table to drop the tables you have transferred.

Comment: Taking these steps could put you in a better position to eventually move the blob data out of the database and into an object store like S3. The existing blob table could be replaced with a table that contains pointers (URIs) to the objects in S3.

Comment: true, could be; or to put somewhere else like aws elastic search and benefit from search if files can be indexed; if files can't be indexed s3 is a good storage option